# Extract 'meaningful row' from a Geotiff/imag?

Tags: qgis, gdal

I have a georeferenced image which looks as below. Due to georefernecing the image is tilted, and the first row of real values of the image goes up from left to right.

If I were to look at it as a matrix, the first row of the matrix would not be the first row of the real image, because of the tilt (i do not know all the correct terminology here).

The image is oriented in relation to the satellite's path direction, slightly diagonally. Perpendicular to the flight path is the range direction (hence also slightly diagonal across).

I have a list of noise values from the metadata that correspond to the range direction. I need to extract the first 'real' row of the image -  not the first row of the matrix which would be straight across. How can I get the first 'real' row of the image?

[image]

Comment: Extract as what, a numpy array?

Comment: if you do not have access to data before georeferencing I would try to 'ungeoreference' and then extract the rows...I would say using the georeferencer to go from whatever coordinates you have to pixel-based local coordinates is pretty straightforward...

Comment: It's possible to do the math in vector space if you know the transformation parameters, but it's way easier to use the old image or transform it back.

Comment: what is  the file format of the image? Is the picture above a screen-grab from qgis, or is it a raw dump of the file?